# Alfresco WebServices API, Change User Password

Tags: alfresco, liferay-6

I am using the Alfresco WebService API, calling it from Liferay, and trying to keep user accounts synchronized. When a logged user tries to access a resource that uses Alfresco, just before I bind a user session, I try to check and create the user in Alfresco.

1. I get an [AdministrationService](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Administration_Web_Service)
2. I'm calling the createUsers function

This worked ok for a new user (the account is created in alfresco), but I cannot find a way to update his/her password. The only relevant function to do this is

```
void changePassword(xsd:string userName, xsd:string oldPassword, xsd:string newPassword)
```

The problem, is that I can't get the old user's Password.

Is there some way to change the password without knowing the old one, or retreive the old one ? An Admin should really be able to change passwords without knowing the old ones in the first place

---

EDIT, I know I should work this by integrating alfresco and Liferay with SSO, but I'm working on a workaround, and I cannot work on the Alfresco installations, so it's not really my call. Besides, I'm curious for that feature, because the way I see it, the Alfresco WebService API will definitely not allow changing passwords.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using a centralised password store between Alfresco and Liferay, eg LDAP?

Comment: @Gagravarr Actually, our Liferay and Alfresco systems, are a part of a large existing System using Shibboleth and LDAP, but the Alfresco-SSO could not work for some reason I don't know. My task is to do this workaround, Since the users will be able to update their passwords and create new accounts through the Liferay Portal

Comment: Alfresco works just fine with LDAP and Shibboleth, so I'd suggest you'd be much better off just fixing your setup to use that rather than hacking round like you suggested doing!

Comment: Yes, you're definitely right, and that was my proposal to the dev team in the 1st place. However, the WS API practically doesn't allow changing passwords, and even if it's a safety - related feature, it still feels wrong to me

Comment: The WS* APIs don't get a lot of love, as (almost?) all the Alfresco developers prefer REST, so that's where all the work goes (for both internal and external APIs). I don't know WS*, but I do know it'd take about 20 minutes to knock up a new REST WebScript API to let you change any user password with some sort of security on it. Alternately, seriously, spend a couple of hours and get LDAP working, it'll save you no end of bother and hassle!

Comment: Thank you for your advices. The point that WS API will not work for my needs is addressing my question, and you are welcome to post it as an answer, so I can accept it